# PC was working when I left but now it isn't

Tags: hardware-failure, desktop-computer

So this morning I was doing my routine and was on my pc doing school work before leaving for class. I get home and turn on my pc and it doesn't boot up. I disconnected my 2nd harddrive (I have 2 installed) and tried booting using only 1 ram in the slot. When I turn it on, everything seems fine. The monitor wakes up from receiving a signal but my bios splash screen (MSI) doesn't show up. All I see is in the bottom right corner is "9C". I cant get into the bios nor my Linux or Windows OS's.

My motherboard is MSI B85-G43 Gaming.

Comment: What motherboard do you have?

Comment: MSI B85-G43 Gaming

Comment: `9c` seems to mean incompatible USB. You tried disconnecting every USB item you have aside from keyboard/mouse?

Answer (score 2):

Okay nevermind. The 9C code meant USB. I had a usb for school files plugged in. I removed it and it booted as normal.